# P4 authentication issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, perforce

How  can i make the user authentication on p4 command line with password (i don't want to create p4config for user and password).
I'm creating java script file which handling few tasks and i need to make authentication somehow for every user.

The closest option that i figured out is as follow: 
1. p4 -u username login

then is prompting for password but i don't know how to fill it up with javascript(node js - p4 module). All of my code is based on P4 Modules and Node JS.

```
var username = process.argv[2];
    p4.run("-u" + username + " " + "login", function (usererror, credentials) {
        if(usererror) {
            console.log(usererror.message);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the P4 Node module documentation it does not seem to offer any sort of authentication support and assumes that you've already authenticated before trying to use it.

Using the command line you would do something like:

```
echo PASSWORD|p4 login
```

and in the APIs the equivalent to that command line redirect would be to use the "prompt" callback to provide the password.

Further, once you've authenticated as a super user, you can do:

```
p4 login USERNAME
```

to gain a login ticket for that user without being prompted for their password.  Since you're writing a tool that wants to run commands as other users without prompting them for a password, you'd probably want to make use of this functionality.

Unfortunately, I can't offer any specific suggestions on how to architect your tool without knowing a lot more about it -- where is it running?  Who's running it?  What does it need to do?  What's the security configuration of your server?  How much do you trust people on your internal network?  Etc.

Comment: Thank you Sam!  I'll use 'echo PASSWORD|p4 login' and will run it separately as bat script. It will work for me.